# multiple font declarations from Google Fonts

Tags: html, css, font-family

I have two Google Font declarations in the 'head' section of an html page as follows:

```
<head>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?  family=East+Sea+Dokdo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

In styles.css I can produce the Charmonan font in html by declaring the following in a class :

```
font-family:Charmonman
```

However, I cannot produce the font East+Sea+Dokdo using the same declaration ie :

```
font-family:East+Sea+Dokdo
```

Any ideas why ? Thanks

Comment: It should be something like `font-family: 'East Sea Dokdo';`. Google tells you this when you turn on "Show Selected Families", the boxes icon at the upper right of the page. (Also, you can collect multiple fonts into a single `<link>` using that same feature.)